# Loop won't exit when dict is empty

Tags: python, loops

Using Python 3:

```
def show_flashcard():    
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return. it then asks if user
        knew definition or not if they do delets the word and
        then asks if they want to continue or quit.
    """
    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])
    import time
    time.sleep(1) # delay for 1 seconds
    print('Did you know the answer')
    user_input = input('y or n: ')
    if user_input == 'n':
        print( 'Do not give  up you can only learn by practice')
        time.sleep(1) # delay for 1 seconds
        user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'y':
        print( 'Congratulations , the word wil now be removed from the dictionary')
    del (glossary[random_key])

# Set up the glossary
glossary = {'1: word1':'definition1',
            '2: word2':'definition2',
            '3: word3':'definition3'}

# The interactive loop
exit = False
while not exit:
    if glossary == {''}:
        exit = True   
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

I can't seem to be able to get this loop to quit automatically when *glossary* is empty. I've tried loads of things, from `if glossary = 0 then exit is true`, but I don't seem to be able to get anywhere. It's driving me mad.

Comment: Some may know what coding language you are using but you don't actually state anywhere in your post which one. Make sure to add the tag for your language too. Also, check out [help] and [ask] for more info about the workings of SO. Good luck!

Comment: You're also missing one line of code at the very beginning, with the function's definition.

Answer (score 1):

You exit condition, `if glossary == {''}:`, will never be true, because you are comparing glossary, a `dict`, to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) that contains a single empty string element.

You can use a `dict` object directly in a condition, and it will evaluate to `False` if it is empty. You can also use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in order to exit your loop immediately:

```
while True:
    if not glossary:
        break
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this was useful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It could be even leaner with:

```
while glossary:
    user_input = ...
```